# ASP.Net Core 6 Hosted Blazor Wasm Not Loading Scripts & CSS Files (When hosted on IIS as Sub Application)

Tags: iis, blazor

I added these lines in `index.html` :

```
<base href="/coolApp/" />

<link href="_content/Blazored.Toast/blazored-toast.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="PublicSite.Web.CLient.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

added below code in `program.cs`:
`app.UsePathBase("/coolApp");`

iis configuration:
[image]

I'm getting below error when hosted in IIS as Sub Application:
[image]

Comment: `err_empty_response` means no data was sent/transmitted. Did you get this error before adding the above code?